# Saving entity with one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I think I have a bad setup for my hibernate database. I have `Citizen` entities who have one to many relationships with `WeeklyCare` entities. Below is the relevant code.

Citizen:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citizens")
public class Citizen {
@Id
@Size(max = 10, min = 10, message = "CPR must be exactly 10 characters")
private String cpr;

@OneToMany()
@JoinColumn(name = "cpr")
private List<WeeklyCare> weeklyCare;
}
```

WeeklyCare:

```
@Entity
public class WeeklyCare {
@EmbeddedId
private WeeklyCareIdentifier weeklyCareIdentifier;
}
```

WeeklyCareIdentifier:

```
@Embeddable
public class WeeklyCareIdentifier implements Serializable {

@NotNull
@Size(max = 10, min = 10, message = "CPR must tbe exactly 10 characters")
private String cpr;

@NotNull
private Integer week;

@NotNull
private Integer year;
}
```

I have some problems when I want to save data to the database:

1. I can't save `WeeklyCare` first, because it requires a `Citizen`.
2. When I send the citizens to my backend, the objects contain a list of `WeeklyCare`. When I try to save the citizens, it gives me this error: `Unable to find Application.Models.WeeklyCare with id Application.Models.WeeklyCareIdentifier@b23ef67b`

I can solve the problem by clearing the list of `WeeklyCare` on the `Citizen` before saving it, and then saving the list of `WeeklyCare` after, but that feels like a terrible way to do it.

I guess I want hibernate to ignore the list of `WeeklyCare` when it saves a `Citizen`, but acknowledge it when it fetches a `Citizen`. Is this possible? Or is there an even better way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I can't save WeeklyCare first, because it requires a Citizen.

You have the "cpr" identifier used in two entities:

- it's the primary Id for `Citizen`
- it's part of the composite Id for `WeeklyCare`

You could, theoretically speaking, create a list of `WeeklyCare` (not with the way it is modeled now though) and later update the associations of each `WeeklyCare` to `Citizen`.

> 2. When I send the citizens to my backend, the objects contain a list of WeeklyCare. When I try to save the citizens, it gives me this
>      error: Unable to find Application.Models.WeeklyCare with id
>      Application.Models.WeeklyCareIdentifier@b23ef67b

The best way to map One-To-Many association is bidirectional. This will also save you from some unnecessary queries Hibernate is generating when using @OneToMany with @JoinColumn only.

1) Remove cpr from `WeeklyCareIdentifier` class (and probably rename the class).

```
@Embeddable
public class WeeklyCareIdentifier implements Serializable {

  @NotNull
  private Integer week;

  @NotNull
  private Integer year;

  //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

2) Remove the composite @EmbeddedId in favor of Long id field:

```
@Entity
public class WeeklyCare {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Embedded
  private WeeklyCareIdentifier weeklyCareIdentifier;

  //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

3) Move to bidirectional mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citizens")
public class Citizen {
  @Id
  @Size(max = 10, min = 10, message = "CPR must be exactly 10 characters")
  private String cpr;

  @OneToMany(
      mappedBy = "citizen",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL, //cascade all operations to children
      orphanRemoval = true //remove orphaned WeeklyCare if they don't have associated Citizen
  )
  private List<WeeklyCare> weeklyCares = new ArrayList<>(); //init collections to avoid nulls

    //constructors, getters, setters

    //add utility methods to manipulate the relationship

    public void addWeeklyCare(WeeklyCare weeklyCare) {
      weeklyCares.add(weeklyCare);
      weeklyCare.setCitizen(this);
    }

    public void removeWeeklyCare(WeeklyCare weeklyCare) {
      weeklyCares.remove(weeklyCare);
      weeklyCare.setCitizen(null);
    }
}
```

and:

```
@Entity
public class WeeklyCare {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    //having reference to the citizen entity from WeeklyCare
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "citizen_cpr")
    private Citizen citizen;

    @Embedded
    private WeeklyCareIdentifier weeklyCareIdentifier;

    //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

I would also recommend to use Long ids for the entities, even if the cpr is unique and so on. Convert the cpr to a normal column and introduce a DB generated ID column which you use in to join with in your internal domain and treat the cpr as a pure user-facing data column.

Comment: Thanks you! When doing it this way, will all WeeklyCare objects created from the database contain a Citizen? I don't really need them to, so that is what held me back from using a bidirectional mapping.

Comment: The association is Lazy in it's definition and WeeklyCare will only hold an ID to citizen. When you load WeeklyCare entities from the DB it won't load the citizens associated with them. Only when you perform getCitizen() on WeeklyCare it will result in SELECT being performed. Keep in mind that the JPA / Hibernate queries are queries to the entities in the persistence context of the JPA provider. It's Hibernate's job to figure if it should fetch from L1 cache, or L2 cache if enabled or actually query the DB.

Comment: Hey, I have now tried this out. When I call `citizenRepository.findAll();` to return it to my frontend, I get a stackoverflow error. This is because the JSON reponse returns each `Citizen` and its list of `WeeklyCare`. Each `WeeklyCare` contains a `CItizen` which again contains a list of `WeeklyCare` and so it continues. How do I solve this?

Comment: That's not caused from the mapping - it's probably by something else in your code. You can checkout another example in this article by the master himself: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: After some research I think it is expected behavior and that it is caused by the bidirectional mapping. I have currently solved it by using the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on `Citizen` in `WeeklyCare`. Not sure if that's the best solution. There's also an annotation called `@JsonIdentityInfo" that might be useful.

Comment: The bidirectional mapping can cause certain frameworks to fail to do their job (e.g. Lombock, Jackson). First I think Entities -which are persistence layer internals should not be directly used for Jackson operations. It's better to convert entities to DTO objects and pass the DTO object UP the call stack until they reach the REST layer - and serialize them there (DTO objects will not contain the fields required for bi-mapping). If you must use Jackson on entities you can help Jackson understand the relationship using JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference annotations.